# Stochastic in finance

Tags: stochastic-processes

I need of a undergraduate guide level to study stochastic process with finances. Starting from a review of probability theory. Eg books, papers or posts. I'll apreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the two volume series, *Stochastic Calculus for Finance* by Steven Shreve.

The first volume discusses mathematical finance for discrete processes, while the second develops the theory for continuous processes, including a treatment of the general theory of Ito calculus.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a undergraduate Stochastic Analysis and Its Applications(for finance mostly), and the recommended text are: 1) D.Williams *Probabilty with Martingales* 2) A.Etheridge *A course in Financail Calculus* 3)B.Okasendal *Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Application*. And I think *Probability Essentials* by J.Jacod & P.Protter is a good book for quick review of probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn a bit of measure theory. Since I am sure that they will discuss about sigma algebras and stuffs like that. Use Royden book as a ref. Also this one is good : Klebaner F.C. Introduction to stochastic calculus with applications